# Select a dynamic link in qtp

Tags: testing, qtp

I am doing record and play in qtp and my scenario is that I have to search for any product in a E-commerce site and then out of the list of that product i have to view details of the very first product.

Comment: Is it flipkart, and do you have an interview shortly? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try descriptive programming. You can effectively use html id property to meet your requirement.

For example : If html id varies like "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_01_lbl", "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_02_lbl".

Then you can use Browser("name:=.*).Page("title:=.*").Link("html id:=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_"&".*_lbl").click

You can modify as per your application.